# Where did Percy sleep when he was away from the Weasleys?

Tags: harry-potter

I was just rereading the sixth book and realized that when Percy and Scrimgeour came to the Burrow, no one had expected Percy even though it was a holiday and that he left after Scrimgeour was through with Harry. So I was curious if anyone knew where Percy Weasley slept during the time he was away from the Burrow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Percy moved to London when he fell out with the other Weasleys.

When Percy fought with his family, he packed his bags and moved to London.

> “He said Dad was an idiot to run around with Dumbledore, that Dumbledore was heading for big trouble and Dad was going to go down with him, and that he – Percy – knew where his loyalty lay and it was with the Ministry. And if Mum and Dad were going to become traitors to the Ministry he was going to make sure everyone knew he didn’t belong to our family any more. And he packed his bags the same night and left. He’s living here in London now.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 4 (Number Twelve, Grimmauld Place)*</sup></sub>

So, he’d be living somewhere in London instead of at the Burrow.

Comment: where in londond though?

Comment: @padfoot It’s not mentioned. All that’s said is he moved to London.